# How do I delete records older than 90 days in QuestDB

Tags: questdb

I am storing IoT sensor data streaming from mutltiple sources into a few tables in QuestDb and because of the huge size of data, I want to keep only the last 90 days. I can see a few ways on their documentation for deleting, but I don't want to `truncate` the table as I would lose latest records. Is there any way instead of making a backup and truncating tables to delete data older than 90 days?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The strategy here should be creating a table that is partitioned and then dropping partitions based on a time value relative to now. The table also has to have a designated timestamp. This example would perform that:

```sql
CREATE TABLE my_table (timestamp TIMESTAMP, x STRING) timestamp(timestamp) PARTITION BY DAY;
```

In your case, you want to drop partitions older than 90 days, you can do that with `ALTER TABLE DROP PARTITION`

```sql
ALTER TABLE my_table DROP PARTITION
WHERE timestamp < dateadd('d', -90, now())
```

It might be useful to know that you can also partition by `MONTH` or `YEAR`.

**Beware** this is destructive and QuestDB can't recover data that's been deleted in this way, either ensure you have a proper backup method in place or that you're certain you do not need the data any more.
There are more details at the [ALTER TABLE DROP PARTITION](https://questdb.io/docs/reference/sql/alter-table-drop-partition/) reference pages.

**Edit:**
There is now dedicated docs for this on the [Data retention](https://questdb.io/docs/operations/data-retention) page